# What kind of adaptor do I need to connect RJ45 / ethernet cable to my Macbook Pro Retina display?

Tags: macbook-pro, ethernet

There is no RJ45 / ethernet port on my macbook.  Do I need a thunderbolt or USB or HDMI adaptor?

Or should I just buy a mini wireless router?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is Apple's [Thunderbolt to Gigabit Ethernet adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD463ZM/A/thunderbolt-to-gigabit-ethernet-adaptor).

There are also assorted USB ethernet adapters available from various sources (including [Apple](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC704ZM/A/apple-usb-ethernet-adaptor)), including a few [Gigabit ones that use USB 3.0](http://www.startech.com/Networking-IO/Adapter-CardsUSB-3-to-Gigabit-Ethernet-NIC-Network-Adapter~USB31000S), but the Thunderbolt one will likely have the best performance, so unless you're using both Thunderbolt ports already, that's the better choice.

Comment: Thanks - what is the benefit of this over a small wireless router?  I am often hot-desking you see.. So need something portable.  Is the thunderbolt a lot faster, and / or quantifiably more reliable?

Comment: Yes more reliable and yes, way faster.

Comment: Don't forget the mini router would almost certainly require another power supply to cart around.